# Send to /dev/null a PHP function "echo" output

Tags: php, json, function, echo

Right now I need to handle with a malformed function which use an *echo* command to output instead of *return*.

When I try to call the function it print in terminal:

```
{"status":"OK","message":"Pong"}
```

I need to store this JSON into an array but not print in terminal this output. I'm building an API and I need to have a clear output. The final value of the variable must be:

```
Array
(
    [status] => OK
    [message] => Pong
)
```

And **don't print anything in terminal**. How can I send the "echo" output produced by the function to /dev/null or something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want get output to variable, you should use [`ob_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [`ob_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) or [`ob_get_clean`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) functions, example:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "Hello ";
$out1 = ob_get_contents();
echo "World";
$out2 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

var_dump($out1, $out2);
/* 
string(6) "Hello "
string(11) "Hello World"
*/
```

or

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "Hello ";
$out1 = ob_get_clean();

var_dump($out1);
/*
string(6) "Hello "
*/
```

example for your code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo '{"status":"OK","message":"Pong"}';
$out1 = ob_get_clean();

var_dump(json_decode($out1, true));
/*
array(2) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(2) "OK"
  ["message"]=>
  string(4) "Pong"
}
*/
```